# c# DataGridView foreach runs less times than expected

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview, foreach

I am trying to make a search for my DataGridView but my foreach loop runs only 4 times instead of row count times...

```
private void btnPretrazi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naziv = "";
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvPretraga.Rows)
        {
            naziv = row.Cells["naziv"].Value.ToString();
            if (naziv.Contains(txtNaziv.Text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yup = " + naziv);
            }
            else
            {

                dgvPretraga.Rows.Remove(row);
                Console.WriteLine("Not = " + naziv);
            }
        }
    }
```

Console output 1 (Anker):

```
Not = B.Disk gumeni FI 125
Not = Tipla Fe M16
Not = Rascepka Hus 300 8.0x90
Not = Civija Jus 230 6x70
```

Console output 2 (Disk):

```
Yup = B.Disk gumeni FI 125
Not = B.Burgija Multi Gar.4-8
Not = Navratka Jus 602M 12x1.25
Not = Anker 753 12x100
```

It works as expected but it runs only 4 times and there are 8 rows in DGV.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what's happening?

Comment: When you remove a row, it will skip the next one.  It should throw an exception for that.  You could also encounter an NRE on the last row if users can add rows

Comment: > The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this `dgvPretraga.Rows.Remove(row);` to see what happens.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvPretraga.Rows)
{
    naziv = row.Cells["naziv"].Value.ToString();
    if (naziv.Contains(txtNaziv.Text))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yup = " + naziv);
    }
    else
    {
        // dgvPretraga.Rows.Remove(row);
        Console.WriteLine("Not = " + naziv);
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through your code adjusting the count and index as you remove rows:

```
for(int i = dgvPretraga.RowCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    naziv = row.Cells["naziv"].Value.ToString();
    if (naziv.Contains(txtNaziv.Text))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yup = " + naziv);
    }
    else
    {
         dgvData.Rows.Remove(dgvPretraga.Rows[i]);
        Console.WriteLine("Not = " + naziv);
    }
}
```